# How to disable PHP mail function on one apache virtualhost?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php.ini

I want to disable PHP function mail via Apache2 virtual host configuration file. I want to do it for one virtual host, not for all virtual hosts, and I don't want disable this function in php.ini

How to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my virtual host:

```
<Directory /dir/to/your/web/root>
...
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "tee mail.out > /dev/null"
...
    </Directory>
```

It worked!

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm getting a apachectl configtest ... /main.conf error:
Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable php system calls on a per-virtualhost basis.

However you can:

- Put this virtualhost into the container and disable sendmail there (method starts from disabling MTA to removing `sendmail` binary entirely)
  this is a method without any limitaions
- Since PHP is an interpreter language you can find all `mail(` occurences with `fgrep -R` and comment out these lines.
  However, this doesn't work for pre-compiled solutions